# Listfield truncates excess rows and is restricted to image size in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have an application where i download images and data and render them on a ListField.The image is shown on the left, and text is shown in rows on the right.
The rows intended to be displayed show information for name,phone number...etc, and they are quite a lot. The issue here is that the listfield only displays three rows (which take up the same height as the image size on the left) and the remaining 5 rows are not displayed.How can i do it so that the row height is not restricted to the height of the image?. The target OS is starting from BB 0S 5.

The draw listrow code is:

```
           public void drawListRow(ListField list,Graphics g,int index,int y,int w)
            {



                Items itemToDraw=(Items)this.get(list,index);

                String name=itemToDraw.getName();
                String desc=itemToDraw.getDescription();
                Bitmap bmp=itemToDraw.getBmp();

                g.drawBitmap(0,y,bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(),bmp,0,0);
                 int ypos=12+y;
                 int wd=bmp.getWidth();
                 int h=bmp.getHeight();
                 int fht=this.getFont().getHeight();
                 int xpos=wd+3;
                 g.drawText("Name: "+itemToDraw._itemName,xpos,ypos,DrawStyle.HCENTER,w-wd);
                 ypos+=fht;

                 g.drawText("Number: "+itemToDraw._Number,xpos,ypos,DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS,w-wd);
                   ypos+=fht;
                   g.drawText("Company: "+itemToDraw._company,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;
                      g.drawText("Year: "+itemToDraw._year,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;

                      g.drawText("Occupation "+itemToDraw._occupation,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;
                      g.drawText("Employer: "+itemToDraw._employer,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;
                      g.drawText("Department: "+itemToDraw._dept,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;
                      g.drawText("Location: "+itemToDraw._location,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;
                       g.drawText("Email: "+itemToDraw._email,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;
                      g.drawText("Phone: "+itemToDraw._phone,xpos,ypos);
                      ypos+=fht;


                      g.drawText("Website: "+itemToDraw._website,xpos,ypos);









                int drawColor=Color.BLACK;


                        g.setColor(drawColor);

                       int yPos=y+list.getRowHeight()-5;
                       g.drawLine(0,yPos,w,yPos);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`drawListRow` invokes to draw every list item, it does not affect on the quantity of displayed list items.

As you have populated a list/array of items you want to display, invoke `ListField` instance method with name [`setSize(int itemsQty)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html#setSize(int))

Make sure that `itemsQty` you are passing to `setSize` method has correct value.

Also, please note that you can scale down big images to make your list look better.

Check for `scaleXXX` methods of the [Bitmap class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html).